# Como criar um nome para checkbox criado com helper do mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Como eu uso o helper do mvc para criar um chekbox e com o nome dele ligado ao checkbox. E se há como eu poder colocar o nome do checkbox à esquerda ou à direita. Fiz assim e não deu certo:

```
<td>@Html.CheckBox("Acesso Remoto")</td>
```

também fiz assim e nada

```
<td>@Html.CheckBox("Acesso Remoto", "Acesso Remoto")</td>
```

Comment: porque ai ele só ta criando o <input type="checkbox"... e não coloque nome separado, coloque AcessoRemoto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Resposta:

E que nesse caso ele só cria o `<input type="checkbox" name="" id="">`, então coloque na frente ou da maneira estabelecida por você!

*Exemplo*

```
<td>@Html.CheckBox("AcessoRemoto", true ou false) Acesso Remoto</td>
```

---

```
<td>Acesso Remoto @Html.CheckBox("AcessoRemoto", true ou false)</td>
```

---

```
<td>@Html.DisplayName("Acesso Remoto:") @Html.CheckBox("AcessoRemoto", true ou false)</td>
```

Comment: Ok, é mais ou menos isso sim. Percebi que o label não fica alinhado com o check. O nome do check fica ligeiramente abaixo do check.

Answer (score 1):

Penso que é isto que queres:

```
<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.campoBD, new { }) Acesso Remoto</td>
```